# Influence function of OLS to check the robustness

Tags: regression, self-study, robust

I understand what is the influence function. I'm just blocked on this exercise. We consider the regression following.
$y_i = x_i^T \beta  +  \epsilon_i$
Can somebody help me to calculate the influence function of $\beta$?

Comment: Since this relates to an exercise, please add the `self-study` tag, read its [tag-wiki](http://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/self-study/info) and modify your question to follow the guidelines on asking such questions. In particular, you'll need to clearly identify what you've done to solve the problem yourself, and indicate the specific help you need at the point you struck difficulty. ... but you also need to clarify something --  what quantity are you calculating the influence function of? The fitted value?

Comment: Check out http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/8344/influence-functions-and-ols